# laravel4 can not sending mail in hotmail and microsoft live

Tags: php, email, laravel-4, hotmail

**I have been able to send user registration confirmation mail  in yahoo, gmail mail server** but i can not able to send mail in hotmail and microsoft live mail server.

This is my mail.php file:

```
  <?php

  return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
|
*/

'driver' => 'smtp',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => 'mail.needagroup.com',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => 465,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => array('address' => 'needagro@needagroup.com', 'name' => 'Needa'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => 'ssl',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => 'needagro',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Password
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
| messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
| connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
|
*/

'password' => '***************',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail "Pretend"
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
| web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
| you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
|
*/

'pretend' => false,

);
```

What is the problem with my code, is there any configuration missing? Its really surprising not to able to send mail only to hotmail and microsoft live mail servers.

**UPDATE**: After a test registration,i got the confirmation message that "We have sent account confirmation email to your email address", but there is no email in my hotmail or microsoft live, not even in the junk or spam folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are able to successfully deliver some emails to some providers, the issue is obviously not in your code or in Laravel.

Some email services have implemented various security and anti-spam policies for incoming mail, some of which could be filtering incoming mail from your server. What you can do:

1. Check your server logs. If Microsoft refuses to deliver mail from your server, the logs should have a return receipt which states the reason.
2. Check your server and DNS configuration. You can use a tool like http://mxtoolbox.com to quickly scan for potential problems

In your particular case, a scan for [mail.needagroup.com](http://mxtoolbox.com/domain/mail.needagroup.com/?source=findmonitors) reveals the following problems:

```
Reverse DNS FAILED! This is a problem.

No SPF records found
```

These really are problems. Specifically, the reverse DNS lookup has become a common anti-spam method and many servers around the world will not deliver email if that fails.

I hope this would at least give you somewhere to start!